# Присвоить <div> блоку произвольные параметры и отправить их используя AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Здравствуйте!

Есть такая конструкция в HTML:

`<div>Автомобиль ВАЗ</div>`

Мне нужно присвоить этому `<div>` дополнительные параметры, например: `{title_URL: vaz, category: rus_marks}`.

Затем, я отправлю серверу эти данные с помощью Ajax в формате JSON.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью какой технологии реализуемо присвоение `<div>` блокам конкретных параметров? Слышал, что можно используя БЭМ, которая вроде как принадлежит Яндексу.

А что ещё есть, может быть можно сделать как-то проще?

Спасибо!

Comment: аттрибуты [data-](http://api.jquery.com/data/) например data-title, data-category, либо же тупо свойства методом jquery  - [prop(propName, value)](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

БЕМ - к вашему вопросу отношение не имеет, и мы им не владеем а продвигаем :)

Записать данные в элемент можно либо создав атрибут у него либо изменив его свойство.

Думаю всю нужную информацию можете найти тут:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr/5884994#5884994
https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties